# Persisting data on android studio

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to persist the state of a page in android studio? For example, I have a click counter and I want to persist the value of the counter so that I can restore it when I re-open the app. Currently, the counter value disappears after closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

use SharedPreferences

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: But can i use SharedPreference to persist data for a specific time? For example, one day only, because i want my data change daily.

Comment: you can use SharedPreferences.Editor.remove() to remove your data (then commit another data)

Comment: but is it going to know the time? like in what time exactly it has to remove the data?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you when saving values. 
[Android saving data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)